# Searching for a feature across multiple shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: attribute-table, features, search

There an extremely useful search tool in ArcGIS that searches everything in the project - is it possible to do this in QGIS,  i.e. searching the whole project for a feature.

Comment: Since not everyone is familiar with ArcGIS, how exactly does that tool work?

Comment: Search for what? An attribute, field, layer?

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to type `af search_value` in the [locator bar](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#locator-bar) (linked documentation) ?

> On the left side of the status bar, the locator bar, a quick search
> widget, helps you find and run any feature or options in QGIS. Simply
> type text associated with the item you are looking for (name, tag,
> keyword…) and you get a list that updates as you write.

Beginning with `af` let you search for features in all the layers in the project.
([all default filters documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#locator-options))

Comment: @jmonticolo strangely, af doesn't return all values for me. I don't really see a pattern as to what is working and not, however. Is there a specific syntax that needs to be used? I tried af 'value searched'.

Comment: @user25976: just start to type `af massachu` if you search the state **Massachusetts**, it's not case sensitive and doesn't require single or double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking how to search for an attribute in the attribute table you can use pyqgis. For example this will go through all added layers and select features with any attribute that are in `search_for`:

```
search_for = {'Arvika', 'Rabbalshede', '61_5', 2121}

for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if isinstance(lyr, QgsVectorLayer):
        to_select = []
        fieldlist = [f.name() for f in lyr.fields()]
        for f in lyr.getFeatures():
            if len(search_for.intersection(f.attributes()))>0:
                to_select.append(f.id())
        if len(to_select)>0:
            lyr.select(to_select)
```

[image]